# How to store xml parser data stored in sqlite database in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, sqlite

I want to insert xml data in Sqlite database.

For Example :

```
UPDATE OBJ_ART SET TITLE = '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US,fr_FR," default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Distribution Sing EN</Title><Title language-id="fr_FR">Distribution Bâtiment</Title></root>', CONTENT = ‘ABCD’, STRUCT_ID = 12709, DISPLAY_DATE = 1422890 WHERE ART_ID = 12716
```

can you please any one guide me how to xml parser data to stored in sqlite database,

Comment: Which do you want to store? The original XML text or some form of the parsed data? Your question is unclear. Either way, update your question with some relevant code of what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: I'm getting xml data from web services .... So to update data base based on ID. XML data i need to update in my sqlite

Comment: @rmaddy : Do u know any answer ?

Comment: As I said, update your question with what you have tried so far. Explain the issues you are having with the code. There is nothing special about an XML string when it comes to storing it in a database table. There are many, many examples of how to use SQLite.

Comment: @rmaddy : I have given my answer it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to insert or update XML data in Sqlite. You just follow some rules.

My example :

```
UPDATE OBJ_ART SET TITLE ='&lt;?xml version=&apos;1.0&apos; encoding=&apos;UTF-8&apos;?&gt;&lt;root available-locales=&quot;en_US,fr_FR,&quot; default-locale=&quot;en_US&quot;&gt;&lt;Title language-id=&quot;en_US&quot;&gt;Distribution Sing EN&lt;/Title&gt;&lt;Title language-id=&quot;fr_FR&quot;&gt;Distribution Bâtiment&lt;/Title&gt;&lt;/root&gt;', CONTENT = ‘ABCD’, STRUCT_ID = 12709, DISPLAY_DATE = 1422890 WHERE ART_ID = 12716
```

It's easy way to do. You just replace XML tags to HTML entities.

```
HTML entities:

 1. < ----- replace to ---- &lt;
 2. > ----- replace to ---- &gt;
 3. " ----- replace to ---- &quot;
 4. ' ----- replace to ---- &apos;
```

I hope it will work. In every where while sending SOAP action also you have to do same thing.

Comment: Why? There is no need to do any of this. Simply store the XML string as-is into the database. The answer by Rob shows you the proper solution.

Comment: it's not possible. We have tried different ways. i hope this is only solution.

Comment: Yes, it's possible and it's simple. But after several requests you have refused to post the code giving you the problem so no one can help you solve the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy : I tried your method.. i'm not getting the result . can u please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

When working with SQLite, one should generally avoid building SQL statements with `stringWithFormat`, but rather use SQL like:

```
UPDATE OBJ_ART SET TITLE = ?, CONTENT = ?, STRUCT_ID = ?, DISPLAY_DATE = ? WHERE ART_ID = ?
```

Then, one would use the SQLite functions [`sqlite3_bind_text`, `sqlite3_bind_int`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), etc., to bind values to the `?` placeholders in the SQL. That will gracefully handle values that happen to have quotation marks within them.

So, call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to prepare the SQL statement, then call `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for each of the columns, and then `sqlite3_step` to perform the SQL and, when done, call `sqlite3_finalize` to release the memory associated with the statement.

Even easier, use a library like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which greatly simplifies this process.